# Passing object to Class method: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: class, excel, pass-by-reference, vba

Hi i'm working in excel 2013 vba, I want to pass a worksheet object to a class function:

'Class module Class1'

```
Sub receive(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    msgbox ws.name
End Sub
```

Calling the class method receive with:

```
Sub passToClass()
  Dim ws as Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
  Dim myClass As New Class1
  myClass.receive(ws) ' Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method
End Sub
```

A simple test that does work are two subroutines in the same module:

```
Sub pass()
   Dim ws as Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
   call receive(ws)
End Sub

Sub Receive(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    msgbox ws.name
End Sub
```

What am I missing conceptually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to remove the parentheses from the call:

```
myClass.receive ws
```

or add the `Call` keyword:

```
Call myClass.receive(ws)
```

Parentheses are only required when calling a routine if:

- You use the `Call` keyword; or
- You are calling a function **and** using the
  return value; or
- You explicitly need to evaluate, or de-reference, the
  variable you are passing.